# How to give an SQLite3 in-memory database persistence efficiently

Tags: sqlite, in-memory-database, in-memory

I very often use SQLite3 databases for quick and dirty internal tools geared toward non-technical level users. One tool is being used much more than expected and needs some optimization. It seems like moving the database to in-memory is the most straight forward way to do this; however, a key issue with this approach is the loss of persistence (I.E.: the application stops and the data in the database disappears).

While I would like to be able to catch the application exiting and trigger a backup of the active database to disk, realistically I don't have the time to handle all the edge cases. I was wondering if there were other ways of backing up the in-memory SQLite3 database to handle unexpected stops to the application?

The simplest way would be to keep a copy of the database on disk and write to it when the in-memory database is written to, but I am not sure how well that performs and I also worry about the two databases becoming unsynchronized.

Comment: You can also look at [`sqlite3_serialize()`](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/serialize.html). This is useful to squirt the bytes to disk.

Comment: If you don't want data loss, just use a normal file-backed database.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make SQLite memory database persistent, and not erased when the connection is terminated / application exit, you can create RAM disk, and use it to create database file there.

Still all data will be lost after machine reboot, so it would be recommended to dump database to regular "hard" file at normal application exit, and recreate it at application startup.